# How do I include an AbstractContextLoaderInitializer into my mvc test execution?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test, junit5

### Background

I'm converting an existing application to using spring web integration tests via `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()`.

I have a class `Initializer` with the following hierarchy:
[image: hierarchy]

When the application runs, that class is automatically detected and included in the context instantiation by `SpringServletContainerInitializer`, and it's important overriding method is called:

```
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ConfigurableEnvironment env = ctx.getEnvironment();
    // other stuff
    env.getPropertySources().addLast(new MapPropertySource("appType", aHashMapImadeWithImportantStuff));
}
```

### The Problem

But during the mock mvc test execution, the aforementioned "appType" property source is missing. (See stack at bottom)

### The Question

What do I do to get this class included in the mvc integration test startup?

---

### The Stack

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:91)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$null$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:194)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:186)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.prepare(MethodTestDescriptor.java:120)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.prepare(MethodTestDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:124)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.company.anApp.config.SomeConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appType' in string value "classpath:/com/company/anApp/config/${appType}/custom.properties"
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:539)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:279)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:539)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appType' in string value "classpath:/com/company/anApp/config/${appType}/custom.properties"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:219)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:571)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:386)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:260)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:539)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: A probably-related concern is how to include my existing tomcat context.xml file into the integration test context.  It includes the appType property, and other stuff, like a datasource.

Comment: BTW, cool to see that you are using JUnit 5 and the `SpringExtension`. ;)

Comment: Very excited about it. The problems I am having are about getting spring mvc integration tests to run - as you say, outside the Servlet container. There are beans (mine, dependencies, and transitive dependencies) which I am struggling to make happy during the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is stated very clearly in the reference manual, the Spring MVC Test Framework does **not** execute within a Servlet container.

Thus, you simply cannot use Tomcat's `context.xml` file, `web.xml`, or a `WebApplicationInitializer` in conjunction with MVC Test.

To set the `appType` property, you have two options:

1. Use `@TestPropertySource`
2. Implement a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` and register it via the `initializers` in `@ContextConfiguration`.